# Can't implement interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class-library, nopcommerce

I'm trying to create a plugin only for admin in **nopCommerce** users and want to create a custom menu item for it, I searched around and found out that I have to implement the Interface `IAdminMenuPlugin` and configure my menu in the BuildMenuItem, I did this in my `MyPluginNamePlugin.cs` file that implements `BasePlugin`, when using the visual studio to automatically implement the default interface and not modify a thing in `BuildMenuItem` I get an error like this:

> Error  1  'Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport.DobaImportPlugin' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'Nop.Web.Framework.Web.IAdminMenuPlugin.BuildMenuItem(Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.MenuItemBuilder)'
>   ....\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport\DobaImportPlugin.cs  8  18 
>   Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport

and after writing my code I get the same error, this is my entire `MyPluginNamePlugin.cs` file:

```
using Nop.Core.Plugins;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Web;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport
{
    public class DobaImportPlugin : BasePlugin, IAdminMenuPlugin
    {

        public void BuildMenuItem(MenuItemBuilder menuItemBuilder)
        {
            menuItemBuilder.Text("Doba Import");
            menuItemBuilder.Url("/Admin/DobaImport/1");
            menuItemBuilder.Route("Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can you point out the obvious mistake ?

I tried to make a class in the Nop.Web project and implement `BasePlugin` and `IAdminMenuPlugin` and didn't get the error, but still don't know how to fix my plugin to implement the interface.

Comment: please post the interface signature. Are the interface and the plugin in same library?

Comment: does both the project have set correct references to all the dependeicies?

Comment: Have you tried: Right click in IAdminMenuPlugin, Implement Interface -> Implement Interface?

Comment: Are you sure the `MenuItemBuilder` that's defined in the method `BuildMenuItem` is being pulled from `Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI`?

Comment: Sorry for this I found the problem "MenuItemBuilder" requiers the Telerik.Web.Mvc library and I download the version 2013.1.219.340  from the nuget packages and the interface implemented the "MenuItemBuilder" with the version 2012.1.214.340, after putting the correct reference it worked.

Comment: @XandrUu, add that as the answer by answering your own question and then in two days you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem "MenuItemBuilder" requiers the Telerik.Web.Mvc library and I download the version 2013.1.219.340 from the nuget packages and the interface implemented the "MenuItemBuilder" with the version 2012.1.214.340, after putting the correct reference it worked.